# Rewrite user directory in user htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible at all to show http://www.example.com/~home/ when http://www.example.com/ is requested? I only have access to htaccess in the "user" directory - is there any way to hide the user dir from the url without doing anything on deeper level than the user?

I've got this based on other Stackoverflow topics but it doesn't work for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    (.*) ~home/$1    [L]
```

Comment: That `.htaccess` looks fine for what you want to do, but it must be in the site root

Comment: ok, I have moved it to root but it doesn't work either

Comment: Change the `[L]` to a `[R=302,L]` while you test. The address bar in your browser should now change to where you're being redirected. That way you can see if anything is happening at all. Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: the URL always changes from example.com/ to example.com and I end up with Apache message so something overrides it? I have it in the <IfModule ..>  but mod_rewrite must be enabled, there is Wordpress in the user directory.

Comment: I have tried to create a htaccess that would simply add the trailing slash (in root) but it won't work either.
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301] 
    </IfModule>`